# configuring bind for self hosting dns

Tags: domain-name-system, bind, dns-hosting

I have been reading about bind for a few days now, but one thing I am still unsure of is, how do I make my DNS settings available to the world?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You install BIND
2. You make sure it starts when the OS does `chkconfig named on`
3. You turn it on immediately `service named start`
4. You configure `/etc/resolve.conf` so that your DNS server looks to itself
5. You configure the `options` statement within `named.conf`:

   (a) Disallow zone transfers: `allow-transfer { none; };`

   (b) Disallow version queries: `version “Not Available”;`

   (c) Allow queries from any IP `allow-query {any;};`

   (d) Configure forwarders if you want to forward queries.

   (e) Configure your zones.

***(And because markdown is broken, my list will start over at #1, but it should be #6)***

6. Create your zone files in `/var/named/`
7. Create reverse lookup zones as needed.
8. Change ownership of the files you created to `named:named`
9. Allow TCP/UDP port 53 through your firewall. Yes, TCP. TCP is used not only for zone transfers, but for large queries (only applicable if you have a huge list of returns to a query though).
10. Restart bind: `service named restart`

### Seem like a lot of work?

It is until you get the hang of it. Running a public DNS server is no joke as miscreants look at it like a rather toothsome morsel. If a DNS server can be hacked, it can be pointed at to deceive the unwitting. Treat it carefully and keep reading up on this.